# Add same event listener function to more than one element

Tags: javascript

```
document.getElementById("composantes").addEventListener("click", function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var selector = $(this);
    console.log('click'+selector.attr('id'));
    ToggleLocalStorage(selector,'expanded');
});
```

Here is my code, I would like it to work for more than one id, like:

```
document.getElementById("composantes, campus, public_target").addEventListener("click", function(event){
```

Comment: querySelectorAll and a loop.

Comment: Since you are getting elements by id (and Ids must be unique) you cannot do what you are looking for.  You can, however, get elements by query selector and loop thru the returned array of matching elements

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `querySelectorAll`. Also probably good to use a named function so that you're not creating more identical functions than needed. It's also helpful if you need to unbind the handler.

```
const els = document.querySelectorAll("#composantes, #campus, #public_target");
for (const el of els) {
  el.addEventListener("click", handler);
}

function handler(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log('click', this.id);
  ToggleLocalStorage($(this),'expanded');
}
```